# How to pass or share variables between Apex:component?

Tags: community

When I try to search on these the only topic that come out is how to pass page controller's variable to component but I could not found how to share variable between two different component.So I am not sure whether is it doable or not?

This is the structure of existing code, one page that consist two components:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" >
<c:componentA id="{!Account.Id} />
<c:componentB id="{!Account.Id} />
</apex:page>
```

Component A and Controller A

```
//component
<apex:component controller="ComponentA_ctrl">
Display {!varA}
</apex:component>

//controller
global with sharing ComponentA_ctrl {
public String varA{get;set;}
public ComponentA_ctrl (){
  init();
}

init(){
List<ObjA> objA=[Select Id From ObjA Where Account.Id=:id Limit 1];
varA = objA.get(0).Id;
}}
```

Component B and Controller B

```
//component
<apex:component controller="ComponentB_ctrl">
Display {!varB}
</apex:component>

//controller
global with sharing ComponentB_ctrl {
public String varB{get;set;}
public ComponentB_ctrl (){
  init();
}

init(){
List<ObjB> objB=[Select Id From ObjB Where Account.Id=:id Limit 1];
varA = objB.get(0).Id;
}}
```

Is it possible if we want to use variable B in component A ?Because I am thinking components will be generated into one same page.If yes, then how?

Answer (score 1):

The id attribute of an apex:component has to be a constant - you can't use a `{!...}`. The section "Accessing Custom Component Attributes in a Controller" of the [Custom Component Controllers](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_comp_cust_elements_controllers.htm) explains how to bind apex:attributes specified for an apex:component to its controller - follow that pattern.

I do not know of any way to obtain a reference to one component's controller properties in another component.

Instead, you could move data you want to share out into a class that you make available as a property of the overall page controller, and pass a reference to that in to each component:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="SharedDataController">
    <c:componentA sharedData="{!sharedData}" />
    <c:componentB sharedData="{!sharedData}" />
</apex:page>
```

with a controller extension that looks like this:

```
public with sharing class SharedDataController {
    public SharedData sharedData {
        get {
            return ...;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: You can get a reference to the page controller in the component controller by passing it as a parameter
`<c:component pageController="this" />`
Using that reference you can send messages between the two controllers.

Comment: @Dominic Didn't realise `this` was available so good to know. If you have a pattern that works well for you, why don't you write it up in a bit more detail as answer to the question here?